# grep: can't open "command"

Tags: perl, grep

I am logging in to the remote machine and executing a command and then grepping the result. I am using Expect module. Here is my sample code.

```
use Expect;
my $exp=new Expect();
$exp->spawn("ssh $hostname\r");
$exp->expect(5,"*]-> ");
$exp->send("command sent here \r");
$exp->expect(5,"*]-> ");
my $res=$exp->before();  // Here i ll get the command output in a variable. The variable contains TCPIP:1.1.1.1 in one line and UDPIP:1.2.2.2 in another line.
my $id=`grep -i TCPIP $res | cut -d ":" -f2 `;
print " The result is $id \n";
```

But here i am getting an error

```
grep: can't open "command sent " .sh: TCPIP not found sh:UDPIP not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do even without `expect`?

```
my $id = `ssh $hostname <your_command> | grep -i TCPIP | cut -d":" -f2`;
```

Comment: @user3381955 put the command to your commandline (not perl) to see what happens: `ssh $hostname <your_command> | grep -i TCPIP | cut -d":" -f2`. Don't forget to replace <your_command> with the one which returns TCPIP and UDPIP.

Answer (score 0):

grep takes a filename as paramater not a string. You need something like this:

```
echo $res | grep -i TCPIP | cut -d ":" -f2 `;
```

Make sure the command works manually via ssh first though.

But consider using perl itself do do the match and cut rather than spawning out to grep, that would be better.

Comment: Need todo some diagnostics. 1) Run your command manually via ssh on command line to check it works OK 2)put a print $res statement in your code to see what is actually being returned before the line that calls grep. Post your latest code and any output from when running your command manually and from your code.

Comment: .. Also try putting quotes round $res in echo command : echo "$res"

Comment: I ran this command ssh $hostname <your_command> | grep -i TCPIP | cut -d":" -f2 and its not working from command line. I have also inserted a print "$res" statement. This is exactly printing the content i need. But grep is not working for that.